# Flot Re-scale Yaxis min/max on X-axis scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have one long unixtime, value Array which is used to initiate a flot chart, and some buttons to change the scale, what I can't seem to be able to do is get Y-axis to scale with the change in X-scale.

Here is an example chart:
http://jsfiddle.net/U53vz/

```
var datarows = //Data Array Here
var options =  { series: { lines: { show: true }, points: { show: true } },
        grid: { hoverable: true,clickable: false, },
        xaxis: { mode: "time", min: ((new Date().getTime()) - 30*24*60*60*1000), max: new Date().getTime(), }
    };
function castPlot() {
window.PLOT = $.plot("#placeholder", [{ data: dataRows }], options
);
};
```

In the official example scaling is automatic and unspecified on the Y-axis:
http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-time/index.html

The only alternative I can think of is looping through the dataset and calculating new Y min/max on each button press. Unless I am breaking some very obvious default function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calculating y-scale, flot does not look at only the "viewable" data but the whole dataset.  Since the data points are still present, the y min/max respects them.  So your options are:

1. Subset the series data down to the desired range and let flot scale both x and y.
2. As you suggested, calculate your own min/max on the y axis.

If you plot get any more complicated than it is now (especially if you start setting up click/hover events on it), I would also recommend you switch to redrawing instead of reiniting your plot.

```
var opts = somePlot.getOptions();
opts.xaxes[0].min = newXMin;
opts.xaxes[0].max = newXMax;
opts.yaxes[0].min = newYMin;
opts.yaxes[0].max = newYMax;
somePlot.setupGrid();
somePlot.draw();
```

**EDITS**

Here's one possible [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/U53vz/1).

Comment: I was hoping there would be a hook for when the view is zoomed in to get the local Y max/min. Any opinion on switching to Highcharts or some other Javascript charting library?

Comment: @user3467349, don't give up on flot so easy.  Here's how I would code it: http://jsfiddle.net/U53vz/1/

Comment: Thanks. Flot just has that 'aged' look, functionality wise I'm a big fan of say being able to insert data processing hooks, and I'm actually worried about other 'nicer' looking libraries being much harder to manipulate in non-standard ways.

Comment: @user3467349, aged look?  I think it's still looking nice!  Seriously, though, if you are looking for a heavier weight library with more out-of-the-box functionality I'd check out Highcharts.  I've used it a alot and It's a very complete solution while still being flexible.  Be careful of two things though, the license is not free for commericial use and since it's SVG based pages with lots of plots/series objects can have high memory use.

Comment: Mhmm, I checked that solution out today, it seems broken and I can't locate the culprit directly, basic going from the 24H time to 'ALL' doesn't work, all the other jumps do.

Comment: ! I still have no idea why it was doing that, but nice fix, this way I don't have to re-init.

Comment: @user3467349, it was doing that becuase I'm an idiot :).  I never added the code to revert back to the whole dataset when the user pressed the `ALL` button.